# Derivation of second moment of area of a circle, a small question

Tags: integration, area

I hope this question will be allowed on math.stackexchange, as the question is a mathematical one even though the subject might be from engineering.

I am trying to derive the formula for the second moment of area for a circle:

Definition of second moment of area about x axis: $I_x=\int_A y^2 dA$

"Translation" into polar coordinates yields $y=r\sin\theta$

What I do not understand is why an infinitesimally small area of a circle is
$dA=rdrd\theta$, and not just $dA=drd\theta$.

Where is the extra $r$ from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following picture:

[image]

The area $dA$ is approximated by the area of a rectangle. The length is $dr$, the width is $rd\theta$, the arc length. Hence $rdrd\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, KittyL. Your drawing made me understand it! :)

Comment: @Akitirija: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you transform variables in a surface integral, you need to introduce a factor inside the integral called a Jacobian. You can think of this as the equivalent to applying the chain rule for changing more that one differential variable, i.e. $dx dy$ to $dr d\theta$ instead of just, e.g. $dx$ to $du$.

For a 1D integral, you would use the chain rule like such:

$$dx = \frac{dx}{du} du$$

For 2D integrals, this becomes:

$$dx dy = J dr d\theta$$

where $J$ is defined as the determinant of a 2x2 matrix:

$$J = \left|
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\\
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$

Hence the extra $r$ that appeared is from the Jacobian.

Similar matrices exist for 3 dimensions (perhaps higher dimensions too?).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is this something we would stumble upon in Calculus 3?

Comment: [For your consideration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), as of the "perhaps" part.